# JQuery 1.8.. not working on webpage as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot seem to work out why this JQuery code isnt working. I have tried this with another HTML page but and it worked with an earlier version of JQuery. But when I try and use this version of JQuery it doesnt seem to work. Any ideas why this is not working?

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="box.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="searchInput" value="Type To Filter">
    <br/>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="fbody">
            <tr>
                <td>cat</td>
                <td>one</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>dog</td>
                <td>two</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>cat</td>
                <td>three</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>moose</td>
                <td>four</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>mouse</td>
                <td>five</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>dog</td>
                <td>six</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JQuery:

```
 $("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
        //split the current value of searchInput
        var data = this.value.split(" ");
        //create a jquery object of the rows
        var jo = $("tbody").find("tr");
        if (this.value == "") {
            jo.show();
            return;
        }
        //hide all the rows
        jo.hide();

        //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
        jo.filter(function (i, v) {
            var $t = $(this);
            for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
                if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        })
        //show the rows that match.
        .show();
    }).focus(function () {
        this.value = "";
        $(this).css({
            "color": "black"
        });
        $(this).unbind('focus');
    }).css({
        "color": "#C0C0C0"
    });
```

Comment: Is your code within a document ready handler? Eg `$(function() { /* YOUR CODE */ });`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this worked. add as answer

Comment: @user3374238 Quentin already answer it

Comment: @user3374238 Thanks, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your code within a document ready handler to ensure it executes after the DOM has been loaded:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is trying to access `#searchInput` from the DOM while the `<head>` is still being parsed (so the element hasn't been added to the DOM).

Either move the script to after the input you are trying to manipulate or wrap it in a function that run on DOM ready or load.

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle with the solution - see the code at:

http://jsfiddle.net/LB4Je/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code goes hede
    // $("#searchInput").keyup ...
}
```

Thats because dom element are not ready when you use the selector `$("#searchInput")`.